# Django - Handle Multiple different Level Nest Model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, data-structures

I have some question about django nested model.

As i know, to handle nested data structure, i must de-serialize every data, then create the object that will connected with ForeignKeyField.

I could handle this by override the `.create()` method by separate every nested data by `.pop()` and create each object model separately. Here is the example how i handle 2 level nested data
(based on documentation: [DRF Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers))

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    child_data = validated_data.pop('child_data')
    parent_obj = ParentModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for data in child_data:
        ChildModel.objects.create(parent_id=parent_obj, **data)
    return parent_obj
```

I have some trouble here. I have multiple multi level data structure, maybe like data below:

```
    "data_a": [
        {
            "data_a_1": [
                {
                    "data_a_1_1": [
                        {
                            "data_a_1_1_1": "example_a_1_1_1",
                            "data_a_1_1_2": "example_a_1_1_2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "data_a_1_2_1": "Example a-1-2-1",
                    "data_a_1_2_2": "Example a-1-2-2"
                }
            ]
            "data_a_2": [
                {
                    "data_a_2_1": "Example a-2-1"
                },
                {
                    "data_a_2_2": "Example a-2-2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**My question is:**

1. What is the best way to handle dynamic data structure like this? It will take a long hardcoded script to handle multiple multilevel data structure by override `.create()` as i mention above.
2. Any other best practice to handle mentioned data-strucure?

Comment: recursion is your friend here.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield 

did you mean this?

Comment: Maybe  you should take a look at: https://github.com/heywbj/django-rest-framework-recursive but I meant recursion as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: I just do some research about recursion, i think your suggestion is what i need to learn, i will back soon to check it.

Comment: @RedCricket any example how to use django-rest-framework-recursive? I still do not understand how to use this properly. Thanks b4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this structure.

I read at the the DRF Documentation, there is a third-party package to handle parent-children relation easily [drf-writable-nested](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#drf-writable-nested)

It helps me a lot to handle this kind data structure problem with out hardcoded `.create()` and `.update()`. This package provide special method to handle parent-child CRUD problem as i mentioned above.

Here is the example:

models.py:

```
class GrandChildModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKeyField(ChildModel, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='grandchild')

class ChildModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKeyField(ParentModel, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='child')

class ParentModel(models.Model):
    parent_name = model.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
```

serializer.py

```
from drf_writable_nested.serializers import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class GrandChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=GrandChildModel
        fields = ["name"]

class ChildSerializer(WritableModelSerializer):
    grandchild = GrandChildSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model=ChildModel
        fields = ["name", "grandchild"]

class ParentSerializer(WritableModelSerializer):
    child = ChildSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model=ChildModelimport 
        fields = ["name", "child"]
```

with this, you can process all kind of nested data :)